# How to authenticate to a dropbox account and get a file with the PHP SDK?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am putting together a small php script that fetches a file from a dropbox account. It's used to import CSV data to client's websites.

Until now, I used shared links from dropbox for such tasks, but now the data is less public, and I want to authenticate to my client's account.

There is a tutorial on https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/php and further, but I wrote down a step-by-step guide I hope is helpful to others for their first steps with the Dropbox API.

I used the PHP sdk, but probably it's quite similar for all the other SDKs.

So, how do I authenticate to a dropbox account and get a file's content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As API 1.x is deprecated, here's a step by step guide for v2

- Log in to Dropbox with the developer's Dropbox account
- Go to the "Dropbox App Console" https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps and register an App (regular Dropbox API). Name it appropriately; the name can't contain "Dropbox". I chose "MYVENDORNAMEGetFile". The app is your own script, it's just registered here. Follow the descriptions. Choose "Permission type: App folder". "Status: Development" is fine; disallow OAuth "Implicit grant"
- As there is no official SDK for PHP anymore, get the well maintained inofficial one from https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk with `composer require kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk`.
- Make a mini-site by creating the three files login.php, header.php and login-callback.php as instructed on https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/wiki/Authentication-and-Authorization ; fill header.php with your info.
- Put that mini-site on a server (doesn't have to be in the same place you use the token).
- Register the link to login-callback (e.g. https://www.mydomain/dropboxauth/login-callback.php) as "Redirect URI" in the Dropbox App Console.
- Give the link to login.php to your "user" and ask them to authentificate via that link. If it's yourself and you use different dropbox account, make sure you use the right one (using various browsers).
- Ask the user to pass you the returned token (you could also have it e-mailed via php) and tell him/her where to find the newly created Dropbox/Apps/MYVENDORNAMEGetFile directory.
- You can now use App Key, App Secret and Token to authenticate and do things, e.g. get a file's contents as documented on https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/wiki/Upload-and-Download-Files

  ```
  // Configure Dropbox Application
  $app = new \Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp($dropboxAppKey, $dropboxAppSecret, $dropboxToken);
  // Configure Dropbox service
  $dropbox = new \Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox($app);
  // Download Dropbox file
  $file = $dropbox->download('/'.$fileName);
  // File Contents
  $itemData = $file->getContents();
  ```

Comment: Dropbox has deprecated API-v1 and seems to have no plans to implement an SDK for PHP. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks for replacements